# I am using fancy box, in my wordpress website, in that title is taking default h2 tag, how i can chage that h2 tag to h1 tag

Tags: wordpress, fancybox

```
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
  <div class=" home_icon_img bt-element bt-fancy-box-element icon-top">
    <div class="bt-icon"><img src="/Home-Icon-01.png" style="" alt="Thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="bt-content">
        <h2 class="bt-title">
          <a style="font-size: 21px;" href="mysite/" title="">Fancy Box Heading</a>
       </h2>
      <div class="bt-desc">
        <p>fancy box description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you installing/using Fancybox?

Comment: Why not edit the markup and replace the `h2` with `h1`?

Comment: @Nico - this is wordpress element , don't have option to change h2 to h1

Comment: @Janis - this is wordpress element i am getting from WPBakery Page Builder when we add elements to page